# Compiling and using AppCompatActivity in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, appcompatactivity

I have the latest `Android Support Library`, `Android Support Repository` and `Google Repository` (`Rev. 23.1, 24, 22` respectively) and working with `Eclipse Mars.1(4.5.1)`

In the process of giving a make-over to an existing app, I am trying to import the `v7.AppCompatActivity` library, closing all other projects in workspace and silent prayers. ( ;-) )

Observations:

- I daresay I have been unsuccessful even after following the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) to the dot.
- **[Ian Lake's blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)** looks all hunky-dory, but Utopian.
- Reading up tons of excellent answers on SO did ***not yet help***. No matter what `target` is set in the `project.properties` page or what `Build Target` is set in the Eclipse Project Properties dialog - just cannot seem to get rid of this (and very similar) compile error(s):

  `android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.`

Going by the number of similar questions, I am surely not alone. Pray, can someone kindly throw some light on how to import the v7 support library without going insane?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eclipse isn't support anymore for Android development. You should move to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers or blogs pointed out the following, except @pkuszewski.

The above issue resolves on

- upgrading to `Android 6 Marshmallow API 6.0` with the SDK manager
- setting the Build Target for the AppCompat project to `Android 6.0`

Did I hear, "Duh"?  :)

Thanks, @pkuszewski!

SDK Manager fragment looks like this, post the fix:

[image]